# UIWebview swipes to another UIWebiew

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, transition, gesture

Total nooob here.  I'm trying to figure out how to implement a 
transition from one UIWebview to another with a swipe and still be able to scroll/zoom w/in each webview.

Each webview should respond normally to all touches/gestures unless a swipe is detected and the boundry of the view/content is at the corresponding edge of the screen (like a paging scroll view).

My content is an html string from a data object.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the UIWebView can handle touches, check my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242197/i-want-to-implement-the-flip-touch-event-in-iphone shows how to detect swipes

Answer (score 2):

Looks like putting a UIWebview in a UIScrollview works fine in iPhone 3.0 - 'Doh!!!

Comment: Apple recommends against this as the touch events can get confused between the scrollview and the webviews. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

There may be reasons to put a UIWebView in a ScrollView, but supporting BOTH swipe and scrolling in UIWebView is not one of them. The UIWebView handles scrolling around on the page just fine by itself, and the view controller that owns it can support swipe to change to something else like another controller by doing the following:

1) In the viewController which owns the WebView implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGr
{
    return YES;
}
```

This allows the gesture recognizer you implement in your webViewController to ALSO get gestures from the UIWebView. Else the UIWebView consumes all of them and will not pass them on to you.

2) To make a distinction between a Swipes and scrolling around on a page. On the actual gesture recognizer you are adding to the UIWebView set the number of touches required to be called a "Swipe" to something like 2 or 3. This allows one finger scrolling on a page and will only return a SwipeGesture when 2 or 3 fingers are used. Do it something like this:

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGR;
 swipeGR = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft)] autorelease];
 swipeGR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
 swipeGR.delegate = self;
 swipeGR.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
 [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGR];
```